# Is there a way to set only ONE of my keyboards to Dvorak layout?

Tags: windows-10, dvorak

I have two keyboards in Windows 10, a normal keyboard and a Bluetooth keyboard. I only want the Bluetooth keyboard to be in the Dvorak layout. Is there a way to do this please? The control panel seems to change to layout for all keyboards only.

Answer (score 1):

No way.

Windows 10 keyboard layout function doesn’t have intelligence to specific different layouts for your different keyboards, every keyboard layout is aimed at all connected keyboards, it’s by design.

What we can do is just hold Windows Key and Space key to switch keyboard layout.